# Why does Mongoose call model.init() each time an application starts?

Tags: mongoose

The snippet below defines a schema, creates a model and saves a document to **MongoDB**. Each time a new document is saved it's automatically indexed.

Models in **Mongoose** have `init` method responsible for creating indexes ([docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.init)). When an app connects to **MongoDB** **Mongoose** calls `model.init()` automatically to build indexes. Now, here's what I don't understand:

What's the point of calling `init` automatically? Do indexes get erased on disconnection from **MongoDB**?

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true
  }
});
const Model = mongoose.model('Kitten', Schema);
const instance = new Model({ name: 'Fluffy' });
await instance.save()
```

Comment: you don't really want to re-create your indexes all the time otherwise it will take a long time every time your application restarts ? I'm guessing the call to `init` is just to make sure the indexes exists.

Comment: @Thomas, I was thinking the same, thank you!

Comment: @Thomas, I just don't get why would previously created indexes not exist?

Comment: It's more if you create new model for version x.x.x of your application then it will make sure the index exists for the new model.

Comment: @Thomas, Oh, right! Makes sense! Thanks! Have a great day, sir!